# magento 2 Grunt watch loads old css when changing imported css file

Tags: magento2, less, grunt, livereload

When I use Grunt Watch my less compile does not work as I expect it to be. 
When I work directly in my theme. less file all perfectly changes and even with livereload works absolutely great.

But when I clean things up a put specific styles in their separate files things are getting weird.

This is my structure

Folder: app/design/frontend/Microdesign/Weldingmart/web/css

```
theme.less
components/header.less
components/footer.less
components/homepage.less
```

So first I need a static content deploy because I get errors like

**FileError: 'components/header.less' wasn't found in pub/static/frontend/Microdesign/Theme/en_US/css/theme.less on line 8, column 1:**

After that, all works what that's concerned but the content seems cached. only after a content deploy my content of the imported files are taking into account. so if I want to use livereload and watch I need to change the CSS in my theme.less and when I'm done I need to copy it into the appropriated field.

Of course, this is not what I want and like.